# assigning owner and finding owner's tasks - rails db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating an application that allows the user to log in, keep the user's session and allow the users to create tasks. Each task has an owner. Tasks should be presented per owner (meaning a user can only see the task he created).

My user table contains: `string name, string username, string password`, and my task table has
`string title  string body integer owner` (should be the user.id)

I already defined sessions and they are working.
inside my sessions controller I have a method that redircat me to the main page in which the user should see all of his tasks (if there are task) + a create new task button or see an empty page with create new task button

```
  def new
    if signed_in?
      redirect_to "/tasks/index"
    end
  end
```

my task/index view contains a method that iterate over the tasks (if they exist) and present them on the screen

```
<h1>tasks</h1>
<%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path %>
<ul>
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <li>
    <div>    
      <p><strong>Title:</strong>
      <%= task.title %></p>

    </div>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

and my task controller: (I have an edit method I am just not typing it in this post)

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, :user_id, :content)
    end
end
```

My routes

```
 resources :tasks
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  root  'sessions#new'
  match '/new',  to: 'users#new',  via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
```

when I am sending my user to the tasks/index I am getting the following error

```
Couldn't find Task with id=index

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end
```

My database is empty, and I was expecting to see the empty page with the create task button. Any ideas why am I getting this error?

Comment: can you paste your routes for tasks controller.

Comment: added routes to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using resources for creating routes, then you should use tasks_path method to redirect to index action in tasks controller:

```
def new
  if signed_in?
    redirect_to tasks_path   #Or, "/tasks"
  end
end
```

You can read about rails routing architecture: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: a) why is that?
b) why both taks_path and /tasks will work?
c) do i need to define the tasks_path in my routes ?

Comment: If you use resources in routes, then it provides the crud operation for necessary routes(index, create, new , edit, update , destroy). You can check all your routes by typing in terminal: rake routes.